# Why is my code looping at just one line in the while loop instead over the whole block?

Tags: python, parsing, soap, dataframe

Sorry for the unsophisticated question title but I need help desperately:

My objective at work is to create a script that pulls all the records from exacttarget salesforce marketing cloud API. I have successfully setup the API calls, and successfully imported the data into DataFrames.

**The problem I am running into is two-fold that I need to keep pulling records till "Results_Message" in my code stops reading "MoreDataAvailable" and I need to setup logic which allows me to control the date from either within the API call or from parsing the DataFrame.**

My code is getting stuck at line 44 where "print Results_Message" is looping around the string "MoreDataAvailable"

Here is my code so far, on lines 94 and 95 you will see my attempt at parsing the date directly from the dataframe but no luck and no luck on line 32 where I have specified the date:

```
import ET_Client
import pandas as pd


AggreateDF = pd.DataFrame()
Data_Aggregator = pd.DataFrame()
#Start_Date = "2016-02-20" 
#End_Date = "2016-02-25"
#retrieveDate = '2016-07-25T13:00:00.000'
Export_Dir = 'C:/temp/'


try:

    debug = False
    stubObj = ET_Client.ET_Client(False, debug)






    print '>>>BounceEvents'
    getBounceEvent = ET_Client.ET_BounceEvent()
    getBounceEvent.auth_stub = stubObj  
    getBounceEvent.search_filter = {'Property' : 'EventDate','SimpleOperator' : 'greaterThan','Value' : '2016-02-22T13:00:00.000'}
    getResponse1 = getBounceEvent.get()
    ResponseResultsBounces = getResponse1.results
    Results_Message = getResponse1.message
    print(Results_Message)
    #EventDate = "2016-05-09"
    print "This is orginial " + str(Results_Message)
    #print ResponseResultsBounces

    i = 1
    while (Results_Message == 'MoreDataAvailable'):
        #if i > 5: break
        print Results_Message
        results1 = getResponse1.results
        #print(results1)
        i = i + 1
        ClientIDBounces = []
        partner_keys1 = []
        created_dates1 = []
        modified_date1 = []
        ID1 = []
        ObjectID1 = []
        SendID1 = []
        SubscriberKey1 = []
        EventDate1 = []
        EventType1 = []
        TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID1 = []
        BatchID1 = []
        SMTPCode = []
        BounceCategory = []
        SMTPReason = []
        BounceType = []

        for BounceEvent in ResponseResultsBounces:
            ClientIDBounces.append(str(BounceEvent['Client']['ID']))
            partner_keys1.append(BounceEvent['PartnerKey'])
            created_dates1.append(BounceEvent['CreatedDate'])
            modified_date1.append(BounceEvent['ModifiedDate'])
            ID1.append(BounceEvent['ID'])
            ObjectID1.append(BounceEvent['ObjectID'])
            SendID1.append(BounceEvent['SendID'])
            SubscriberKey1.append(BounceEvent['SubscriberKey'])
            EventDate1.append(BounceEvent['EventDate'])
            EventType1.append(BounceEvent['EventType'])
            TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID1.append(BounceEvent['TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID'])
            BatchID1.append(BounceEvent['BatchID'])
            SMTPCode.append(BounceEvent['SMTPCode'])
            BounceCategory.append(BounceEvent['BounceCategory'])
            SMTPReason.append(BounceEvent['SMTPReason'])
            BounceType.append(BounceEvent['BounceType'])

        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ClientID': ClientIDBounces, 'PartnerKey': partner_keys1,
                       'CreatedDate' : created_dates1, 'ModifiedDate': modified_date1, 
                       'ID':ID1, 'ObjectID': ObjectID1,'SendID':SendID1,'SubscriberKey':SubscriberKey1,
                       'EventDate':EventDate1,'EventType':EventType1,'TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID':TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID1,
                       'BatchID':BatchID1,'SMTPCode':SMTPCode,'BounceCategory':BounceCategory,'SMTPReason':SMTPReason,'BounceType':BounceType})          
        #print df1
        #df1 = df1[(df1.EventDate > "2016-02-20") & (df1.EventDate < "2016-02-25")]
        #AggreateDF = AggreateDF[(AggreateDF.EventDate > Start_Date) and (AggreateDF.EventDate < End_Date)]
    print(df1['ID'].max())            
    AggreateDF = AggreateDF.append(df1)   
    print(AggreateDF.shape)
    #df1 = df1[(df1.EventDate > "2016-02-20") and (df1.EventDate < "2016-03-25")]    
    #AggreateDF = AggreateDF[(AggreateDF.EventDate > Start_Date) and (AggreateDF.EventDate < End_Date)]
    print("Final Aggregate DF is: " + str(AggreateDF.shape))

    #EXPORT TO CSV
    AggreateDF.to_csv(Export_Dir +'DataTest1.csv')
        #with pd.option_context('display.max_rows',10000):
            #print (df_masked1.shape)
        #print df_masked1 



except Exception as e:
    print 'Caught exception: ' + str(e.message)
    print e
```

Before my code parses the data, the orginal format I get of the data is a SOAP response, this is what it look like(below). **Is it possible to directly parse records based on EventDate from the SOAP response?**

```
}, (BounceEvent){
   Client = 
      (ClientID){
         ID = 1111111
      }
   PartnerKey = None
   CreatedDate = 2016-05-12 07:32:20.000937
   ModifiedDate = 2016-05-12 07:32:20.000937
   ID = 1111111
   ObjectID = "1111111"
   SendID = 1111111
   SubscriberKey = "aaa@aaaa.com"
   EventDate = 2016-05-12 07:32:20.000937
   EventType = "HardBounce"
   TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID = "aa111aaa"
   BatchID = 1111111
   SMTPCode = "1111111"
   BounceCategory = "Hard bounce - User Unknown"
   SMTPReason = "aaaa"
   BounceType = "immediate"
```

Hope this makes sense, this is my desperately plea for help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is it currently outputting? Can you try to clarify what you are asking, as of right now it seems a bit unclear?

Comment: Sorry about that. It is currently outputtnig the string "MoreDataAvailable" which I believe is happening on line 44 "print Results_Message"

What I am asking is:

1. How do I prevent the code from just looping on what I believe is line 44 and actually run through the code, and put data in the data frames TILL "Result_Message" does not equal "MoreDataAvailable"

2. How do I setup logic in either the API call itself or the dataframe where I can control what eventDate is being used. For example I want to only see records after 2016-07-20 till 2016-07-21

hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be updating `Results_Message` in your loop, so it's always going to have the value it gets in line 29: `Results_Message = getResponse1.message`. Unless there's code involved that you didn't share, that is.

Comment: I am sharing all the code. "getResponse1.message" contains the string "MoreDataAvailable" so once that changes I want the loop to stop. 

Could you please show me how to update the "Results_Message"?